# Как удалить из массива слова имеющие определённую комбинацию букв

Tags: javascript, массивы

### Вот текст задачи:

Исключить из введенного предложения все слова, которые содержат заданную пользователем комбинацию из двух символов.

#### Что пытался сделать я

Пытался пропускать массив через цикл, например [`"Привет", "Как", "Дела"]`
В ходе цикла брал первое слово, и через `.split('')` расщеплял его на буквы - [`"П","р","и","в","е","т"]`.

Далее через вложенный цикл проверял, если ли буквы совпадающие с комбинацией. Тут и возникли проблемы,не получается проверить, есть ли обе буквы в слове. Так же не знаю, как удалить из массива слово в котором будет совпадение.

**Код, который уже есть:**

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var key = document.getElementById('key');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', keyDeleter); 

function keyDeleter() { 
  var Arrkey = key.value.split('');
  var ArrValue = input.value.split(' ');
  for(var i = 0; i < ArrValue.length; i++) {
    console.log(ArrValue);
    var newArr = ArrValue[i].split(''); // Расщепление на буквы 
    console.log(newArr); 
    for(var j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
       if(newArr[j] == Arrkey[0]) {
          console.log('Совпадение');
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте к ответу тот код что у вас уже получился.

Comment: 10 минут, я его уже удалил.Сейчас перепишу!

Comment: var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var key = document.getElementById('key');
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', keyDeleter);
  function keyDeleter(){
   var Arrkey = key.value.split('');
   var ArrValue = input.value.split(' ');
   for(var i = 0; i < ArrValue.length; i++){
    console.log(ArrValue);
    var newArr = ArrValue[i].split(''); // Расщепление на буквы
    console.log(newArr);
    for(var j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++){
     if(newArr[j] == Arrkey[0]){
      console.log('Совпадение');
  }
  }
  } 
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function deleteElemsWith (arr, str) {
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(arr[i].includes(str)) {
            delete arr[i]
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

let newArr = deleteElemsWith(['aabbcc', 'aacc', 'zzz'], 'aa');
console.log(newArr); // ,,zzz
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```js
let strs = ["Быть или не быть — вот в чём вопрос.","Достойно ли терпеть безропотно позор судьбы","Иль нужно оказать сопротивленье?","Восстать, вооружиться, победить","Или погибнуть, умереть, уснуть?","И знать, что этим обрываешь цепь сердечных мук","И тысячи лишений, присущих телу!"];
let result = document.querySelector('#result');

document.querySelector('#inp').addEventListener('input', function(){
  let val = this.value.trim().substr(0, 2);
  
  if(val.length !== 2){
    result.innerHTML = '';
    return;
  }
  
  result.innerHTML = strs.map(s => !s.includes(val) ? s : `<span class='found'>${s}</span>`).join("\n");
});
```

```css
.found{
  color: lightblue;
}
input{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='inp' placeholder='Введите 2 символа (e. g. бы)!' maxlength='2' />
<pre id='result'></pre>
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста.....